# `WHERE col IN` with named parameters

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

In the example on how to use [parameterized queries with an IN clause](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#where-col-in-values), the syntax is as follows:

```
const data = [1, 'two', 3, 'four'];

db.any('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($1:csv)', [data])
    .then(data => {
...
```

I can't seem to get this to work for named parameters:

```
db.manyOrNone('SELECT widget FROM widgets WHERE id IN ($(ids:list))', 
              { ids: [1, 2, 3] })
```

(I'm using `:list` since it appears to be [interchangeable](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#csv-filter) with `:csv`).
I've tried various combinations like:

- `($(ids):list)` (syntax error at or near ":")
- `(${ids:list})` (syntax error at or near "$")

I keep getting invalid syntax errors from Postgres. Is this supported? Or do I have to pass the parameters as an array and reference them like in the example?

**Versions:**

- Postgres: 9.5.7
- pg-promise: 5.7.1

**UPDATE**
I changed my param to be `... WHERE widget IN ($(ids:csv))...` and it works now, So it seems that `:list` and `:csv` are *not* interchangeable.

Comment: The example seems correct, so something else must be off. You should publish the complete example of calling the query method, exactly the way you're using it.

Comment: @vitaly-t I updated the question with the actual filter I was using along with versions. Beautiful library, by the way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an ancient version of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise). The current version is 8.4.4, and you are using 5.7.1

Alias `:list` is fully interchangeable with `:csv`, but it was added much later than v5.7.1

Upgrade to the latest version, and it will work with `:list` as well.

Also assume that everything that's in the current documentation refers accordingly, to the current version of the library.