# NodeJS, pg-promise and array as parameter

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

Running `NodeJS` and `pg-promise`.

I've got an array:

```
let my_array = new array('x', 'y', 'z');
```

I'm trying to pass this as a parameter to my `PostgreSQL` query with `pg-promise`:

```
db_webhooks.any('SELECT cars FROM my_cars WHERE id IN ($1)', [my_array])
  .then...
```

But it fails with type error.
I've tried to `.join` the array, but also get error, as it result in a string `'x,y,z'` instead of `'x','y','z'`.

Printing out the debug/query called gives me:

```
QUERY: SELECT cars FROM my_cars WHERE id IN (array['x','y','z'])
```

This should be:

```
QUERY: SELECT cars FROM my_cars WHERE id IN ('x','y','z')
```

Comment: `[my_array]` will create an array with one element, namely your array `new array('x', 'y', 'z')`. Try just `db_webhooks.any(... , my_array)`

Comment: That gives me `QUERY: SELECT cars FROM my_cars WHERE id IN ('x')`, so only the first elements is included.

Comment: Seems like `... id IN ($1:csv)` solves the issue.

Comment: Then it appears that your call does not accept an array parameter but wants a comma-separated string, and then `my_array.join(",")` may do the trick.

Comment: And if you found a solution to your own problem, please don't hesitate to post your own answer.

Comment: See these posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720420/node-postgres-how-to-execute-where-col-in-dynamic-value-list-query/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50381949/where-col-in-with-named-parameters

Comment: @AlfredBalle Why did you never accept my answer?

Answer (score 5):

The library supports [CSV Filter](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise#csv-filter) for this purpose:

```js
await db.any('SELECT cars FROM my_cars WHERE id IN ($1:csv)', [my_array])
/*=> SELECT cars FROM my_cars WHERE id IN ('x', 'y', 'z') */
```

or you can use `:list`, which is the same:

```js
await db.any('SELECT cars FROM my_cars WHERE id IN ($1:list)', [my_array])
/*=> SELECT cars FROM my_cars WHERE id IN ('x', 'y', 'z') */
```